# Implementing luigi dynamic graph configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, luigi, data-pipeline

I am new to luigi, came across it while designing a pipeline for our ML efforts. Though it wasn't fitted to my particular use case it had so many extra features I decided to make it fit.

Basically what I was looking for was a way to be able to persist a custom built pipeline and thus have its results repeatable and easier to deploy, after reading most of the online tutorials I tried to implement my serialization using the existing `luigi.cfg` configuration and command line mechanisms and it might have sufficed for the tasks' parameters but it provided no way of serializing the DAG connectivity of my pipeline, so I decided to have a WrapperTask which received a `json config file` that would then create all the task instances and connect all the input output channels of the luigi tasks (do all the plumbing).

I hereby enclose a small test program for your scrutiny:

```
import random
import luigi
import time
import os


class TaskNode(luigi.Task):
    i = luigi.IntParameter()  # node ID

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.required = []

    def set_required(self, required=None):
        self.required = required  # set the dependencies
        return self

    def requires(self):
        return self.required

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('{0}{1}.txt'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.i))

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('inside {0}{1}\n'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.i))
        self.process()

    def process(self):
        raise NotImplementedError(self.__class__.__name__ + " must implement this method")


class FastNode(TaskNode):

    def process(self):
        time.sleep(1)


class SlowNode(TaskNode):

    def process(self):
        time.sleep(2)


# This WrapperTask builds all the nodes 
class All(luigi.WrapperTask):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        num_nodes = 513

        classes = TaskNode.__subclasses__()
        self.nodes = []
        for i in reversed(range(num_nodes)):
            cls = random.choice(classes)

            dependencies = random.sample(self.nodes, (num_nodes - i) // 35)

            obj = cls(i=i)
            if dependencies:
                obj.set_required(required=dependencies)
            else:
                obj.set_required(required=None)

            # delete existing output causing a build all
            if obj.output().exists():
                obj.output().remove()  

            self.nodes.append(obj)

    def requires(self):
        return self.nodes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

So, basically, as is stated in the question's title, this focuses on the dynamic dependencies and generates `a 513 node dependency DAG` with `p=1/35 connectivity probability`, it also defines the All (as in make all) class as a WrapperTask that requires all nodes to be built for it to be considered done (I have a version which only connects it to heads of connected DAG components but I didn't want to over complicate).

Is there a more standard (Luigic) way of implementing this? Especially note the not so pretty complication with the TaskNode **init** and set_required methods, I only did it this way because receiving parameters in the init method clashes somehow with the way luigi registers parameters. I also tried several other ways but this was basically the most decent one (that worked)

If there isn't a standard way I'd still love to hear any insights you have on the way I plan to go before I finish implementing the framework.

Comment: related unanswered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563175/how-to-enable-dynamic-requirements-in-luigi

Comment: did you ever consider airflow over luigi? I use it for doing more or less exactly what you said in your question: https://airflow.apache.org/

Comment: I took a short look at it but it seemed more centered around cmdline and not python, is that just a lazy first impression?

Comment: i woulddn't necessary say that. it comes with a web ui and is centered around scheduled or triggered execution of your DAGs. you can run DAGs from the command line, manually, if you like. 

it is a very large package, though, with a few dependencies that might be overkill for your situation. it requires at least a sqlite db, for instance.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds interesting and rumor has it that it is better maintained than luigi now, I'll probably look at it next round (or next job I have) but I'm kind of full steam ahead with luigi by now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987595/luigi-overriding-task-requires-input) yesterday with a demo. I based that almost entirely off of the [example in the docs.](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/examples/dynamic_requirements.py). In the docs, assigning dynamic dependencies by `yeild`ing tasks seems like the way they prefer.

`luigi.Config` and dynamic dependencies can probably give you a pipeline of almost infinite flexibility. They also describe a dummy `Task` that calls multiple dependency chains [here,](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/luigi_patterns.html#triggering-many-tasks) which could give you even more control.